# Mapview to image convert

Tags: android, bitmap, android-mapview

I need to convert mapview to bitmap image. I used the code as below:

```
MapView mapview = new MapView(this, "map_id_String");
mapview.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
MapController mc = mapview.getController();
GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint((int) (36 * 1E6),(int) (36 * 1E6));
mc.animateTo(p);
mc.setZoom(20);
Bitmap viewCapture = null;
mapview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
mapview.layout(0,0,400,400);
mapview.buildDrawingCache();
viewCapture = Bitmap.createBitmap(mapview.getDrawingCache());
mapview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
return viewCapture;
```

But this code returns the image of view at the beginning, the map which has not been fully resolved. I need to wait it until mapview is fully resolved.

Comment: My aim is to rotate mapview according to sensor data i found this code http://code.google.com/p/mapsadroidproject/source/browse/trunk/MapsDemo/src/com/example/android/apis/view/MapViewCompassDemo.java but it looks old and i don't trust the code. The logic behinds the code, there is a custom ViewGroup class which implements SensorListener, the rotations are done in ViewGroup class's dispatchdraw method. Moreover, there is a custom Canvas class.I did not understand why he needed a custom canvas class.

Comment: Please revisit some of your older questions and accept answers. This will make people more likely to answer your new question :)